# Get variable outside module request when asynchronous

Tags: javascript, cheerio, npm-request

Hi I'm trying to get the id variable that it's returned inside request in an asynchronous process using request and cheerio.

I've tried by returning a Promise but that didn't work.

```js
let id;

    request(mainUrl, function(err, res, body) {  
                
        let $ = cheerio.load(body)

        var links= $(".book").map(function(){
            return $(this).attr("href");
        }).get()

           
        var url= links[0]


        var getId= url.match(/book\/show\/(\d+)/)


        id= getId[1]
        //This is the id I'm getting: "36474"
           
        return Promise.resolve(id)

    });


    .then((value)=>{
     console.log(id)

    })
```

Comment: what request lib are you using? looks like you're using a callback-based one, might not support `.then`

Comment: *"didn't work"* is not a proper technical problem diagnosis

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it:

```js
let id;

let promise= new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
   request(mainUrl, function(err, res, body) {  
            
      let $ = cheerio.load(body)

      var links= $(".book").map(function(){
       return $(this).attr("href");
     }).get()

       
      var url= links[0]


      var getId= url.match(/book\/show\/(\d+)/)


      id= getId[1]
      //Ex: => "36474"
       

      return resolve(id)

});
})


promise
.then((value)=>{
 console.log(id)

})
```